# Select missing row between two dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new here and this is my first question. I'm learning python recently (beginner). I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
Id      Name       URL                Location
1       Google     www.google.com     USA
2       Facebook   www.facebook.com   USA
3       Twitter    www.twitter.com    USA
```

df2:

```
Id      Name       URL                Location
1       Google     www.google.com     USA
2       Facebook   www.facebook.com   USA
```

I want the output to return the rows that are not in df2 and are in df1. My output should be the following :

df3:

```
Id      Name       URL                Location
 3       Twitter    www.twitter.com    USA
 4       yahoo      www.yahoo.com      USA
```

What I did for now is the following:

`common = df1.merge(df2,on=['URL'])`

`final = df1[(~df1.URL.isin(common.URL))]`

but i am not getting a true number.

can someone help ?

Comment: `df2[~df2['URL'].isin(df1['URL'])]`

Comment: @QuangHoang still not working. 
my df1 now has 30 000 rows
my df2 has 29 496 rows
the difference is giving me only 55 rows :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the Dataframe with only URLs (or any other columns values) from df1 as below

```
df3=df1[~df1['URL'].isin(df2['URL'])]
```

[image]